# When are $\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ both rational?

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers

I've seen a bunch of related questions, but none lead me to a solution to this problem:

**Is there any "easy" characterisation of $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$ such that $\cos\alpha\in\mathbb Q$?**

It feels like there should be only "few" such numbers.
**Are there only finitely many?**

Comment: See [Niven's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem)

Comment: I assumed the question has $\alpha$ in radians, so Niven does not apply.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, his is indeed what I meant.

Comment: There's $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Well...if $\cos(x)$ is rational, then $\sin(x)$ is at least algebraic, so $e^{ix}$ is algebraic.  Lindemann-Weiersrtass then shows that $x\in\mathbb Q\implies x=0$.

Comment: @lulu That's perfect, thank you! If you post an answer, I shall gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested in the comments:

It follows from Lindemann-Weierstrass that $\alpha=0$ is the only example.  To see that:

Suppose $\cos(\alpha)$ is algebraic.  Then, of course, $\sin(\alpha)$ is also algebraic.  It follows that $e^{i\alpha}$ is algebraic.  But Lindemann-Weierstrass tells us that, unless $\alpha=0$, this implies that $\alpha$ is transcendental.  In particular, it can not be rational (unless it is $0$).